# Laravel autologin

Tags: php, laravel

Ситуация такая:

Пользователь добавляется в ручную в админ-панели, ему на почту падает письмо, по которому он переходит, завершает регистрацию и его логинит.

Проблема в следующем:

Laravel логинит пользователя, но при редиректе - браузер ведет себя так, как будто никакого автологина и не было и заставляет логинится в ручную.

Код для автологина следующий:

```
Auth::login($user, true);
$isLogin = Auth::check(); //true
$user = Auth::user(); //Valid user instance
```

Перед этим было опробовано:

```
auth()->guard()->login($user, true);
```

Результат тот же.

Прощу помощи.

*UPD*. Laravel v5.5

Comment: Какая версия Laravel?

Comment: @Orange_shadow версия 5.5

Comment: Похоже на то, что у вас Session Middleware не прошла, но я так понимаю этого быть не может  ? вы ж редиректите не в middleware ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow боюсь не совсем понял, что Вы имеете в виду

Comment: Где вы делаете редирект ? можно пример кода авторизации с названием файла и показать роут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с сессией. Вызов `session()->flush()` решил проблему.